# can somebody tell me why this is happening?

Tags: jquery

i wanna to alert only the last value not all the clicked class
example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".a").click(function(){
 var a = $(this).children(".b").val();
    $("#b").click(function(){
       alert(a);            
    });
});
```

});​

[here is the code](http://jsfiddle.net/3dnDj/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're stacking the click events.

Use [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove previous click events added to `$("#b")`

Change to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".a").click(function(){
 var a = $(this).children(".b").val();
    $("#b").unbind("click");
    $("#b").click(function(){
       alert(a);            
    });
});
});​
```

[**-- See Working Demo --**](http://jsfiddle.net/3dnDj/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a variable outside of the handlers and update it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cur = 0;
    $(".a").click(function() {
        cur = $('.b', this).val();
    });
    $("#b").click(function() {
        alert(cur);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GVqHE/

Comment: Needs a bit of work if you use this method. Clicking `#b` before `.a` causes `undefined` alert

Comment: @Curt I have set the default value for the `cur` variable, it's not

Comment: @undefined Now itll return `0`. I suppose it depends on requirements, but I'd expect no alert to be shown.

Comment: Better solution wouldve been `if (cur) { alert(cur); }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var a = "" ;
    $(".a").click(function(){
    a= $(this).children(".b").val();

    });
    $("#b").click(function(){
           alert(a);            
        });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3dnDj/2/

Comment: Needs a bit of work if you use this method. Clicking `#b` before `.a` causes `undefined` alert

Answer (score 0):

Use the :eq selector to choose a specific child from within a list of elements
e.g. `$('.a:eq(2)')` would select the 3rd element.

See: http://api.jquery.com/eq/